# Code for left/right only output on earphone?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning to code in android studio and as practice i wish to make app in which when i click left button sound is played in left of earphone,when right is clicked sound is played in right earphone .

Comment: Instead of asking for the code - perhaps you should ask which API's or libraries would be a good starting place for this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this will work for you or not,but i suggest you to use [Soundpool](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/getting-your-feet-wet-in-androids-soundpool/) for that,and use setVolume method.

```
setVolume(int streamID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume)
```